# N-ary tree implementation

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I am new to C++ and I'm trying to create to learn more about K-ary Trees. Could you help me define a `KAryTreeNode`, assuming the information stored in the node is a character array.

Comment: “N-ary K-ary” – did you really intend to put this twice? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: Some people using N-ary and some K-ary. It is the same thing

Comment: That’s what I meant. So it’s redundant. Use one convention, don’t mix and match. Also, on Stack Overflow you need to show your research so far and what code you’ve written. We do not generally provide source code.

Comment: For fixed *k*? For variable *k*? What's the purpose of the tree?

Answer (score 2):

```
class KAryTreeNode{

char * data;
vector<KAryTreeNode *> children;

};
```

something like that.